# Retrieving data inside a value that came with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a code structure as shown below.
How can I get the value in State: `[b'8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32']` coming in loop?

i.e., I want to get the "state" value.

```
# send request
reply = srv.SendPacket(req)
print(reply)

if reply.code == pyrad.packet.AccessAccept:
    print("access accepted")
else:
    print("access denied")

print("Attributes returned by server:")
for i in reply.keys():
    print("%s: %s" % (i, reply[i]))
```

```
(venv) host@local-pc:~/Documents/Workshop/radiusapplication$ python3 test1.py 
AuthPacket([(18, [b'Enter Passcode']), (24, [b'8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32'])])
access denied
Attributes returned by server:
Reply-Message: ['Enter Passcode']
State: [b'8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32']
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. At the end of the code you are already printing that value. Is your question how to get one value out of a list? - use indexing for that.

Comment: Yeah man. I want to get the value in state.

Comment: Have you tried to use `reply['State'][0]`?

Comment: I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted

```
reply["State"][0].decode()
```

(if you want to get it as a *string*; if you are satisfied with receiving it as a *byte object*, remove the `.decode()` part).

---

*The explanation:*

You may progressively obtain these values:

```
>>> reply["State"]                          # result: value of "State", a one-element list
```

> ```
> [b'8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32']
> ```

```
>>> reply["State"][0]                       # result: the 1st element of that list
```

> ```
> b'8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32'
> ```

```
>>> reply["State"][0].decode()              # result: that 1st element converted to string
```

> ```
> '8e4d29d4-c144-4d18-aecc-77f4567d8d32'
> ```